# Updating row in MYSQL from PHP form

Tags: php, mysql

Outline of what I'm trying to do: I have a table in my db called **agents** , one of the columns in the table is called `activated`. I want to be able to enter the agents *username* (row 1 in the agents table) and then have the row within the column for `activated` update to a 1 `(instead of the default of 0 which identifies the user as not activated)`. I'm clearly going wrong, can someone point out where?? Thank you all for your time.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
$userId = $_SESSION['id'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
} else {
header('Location: home.php');
die();
}
?>
<?php
if($_POST['submit']){
include_once("connection.php");
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$sql = "SELECT username, FROM agents WHERE username = '$username'";
$query = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
if ($query) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$dbUsername = $row[1];
}
?>
<?php
$dbUsername = $row[1];
if ($username == $dbUsername){
$sql2 = "UPDATE agents SET activated ='1' WHERE $username = username";
$query2 = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql2);
header('Location: userstaff.php');
} else {
echo "Problem detected.";
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Activate agent</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Activate agent </h1>
<form method="post" action="activateagent.php">
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="activate" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you checked the sql error message returned after you run the update, you may not have needed to ask this question... Missing single quotes around string literal. Next time pls also provide detailed error message or description of the unexpected behaviour instead of writing that sg has gone wrong. Your question does not provide any help whatsoever to those who may try to provide you with an answer.

Comment: No action is taken when the execution of the SELECT query encounters an error. (The error message is available using mysqli_error.) If the execution of the SELECT is successful (which it won't be, due to the syntax problems in the SQL), there is no check whether a row is fetched. Also, the code appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. StackOverflow is a question/answer site, *not* a debugging service.

Comment: The error is that it is echoing: "problem detected".

Comment: @spencer7593 I'm not asking for a de-bugging service I just need a little help with the syntax as i'm a beginner with this. If you can help i'd appreciate it.

Comment: **mysqli_error** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  **mysqli_prepare** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php **mysqli_stmt_bind_param** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra comma(,) in your select query

```
$sql = "SELECT username, FROM agents WHERE username = '$username'";
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback but removing this doesn't fix the issue which is the error : echo "problem detected".